# Enviar processo para o servidor e liberar o usuário

Tags: python, django

Estou tendo um problema em uma aplicação que usa 3G e está bem lento pra manter o usuário esperando.

Alguém sabe alguma biblioteca que eu possa mandar a informação para o servidor e liberar o usuário?

A informação é um lote com 100 conjuntos de números que serão adicionados no banco um a um.

Não se trata de um código assíncrono porque eu não preciso informar ao usuário que deu erro ou acerto. Simplesmente vou mandar a informação para o servidor e pronto.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), pois seu problema no meu entendimento é fazer o Django iniciar um processamento demorado fora do ciclo requisição-resposta. É isso mesmo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) para fazer isso.

Trata-se de uma biblioteca assíncrona de fila de tarefas baseada em passagem de mensagens distribuídas. É focada em operações em tempo real, mas suporta agendamento também.

O Celery é muito indicado pra fazer o que você precisa: rodar alguma coisa depois que a requisição da web estiver terminada. Além disso [é confiado e usado por apps como o Instagram](http://blogs.vmware.com/vfabric/2013/04/how-instagram-feeds-work-celery-and-rabbitmq.html).

Basicamente você escreve uma tarefa em Python e configura um "worker" do Celery. Então, ao processar as requisições, você coloca a execução numa fila que será executada por esse worker.

O fato de você não precisar informar o usuário sobre o resultado não significa que não há necessidade de execução de código assíncrono. A definição de assíncrono é execução em paralelo.

Answer (score 2):

Opa!

Dependendo de o que você precisa, o celery pode ser um pouco demais. 
Quando tenho algo simples que preciso fazer esse esquema de filas, e processamento assíncrono, eu uso o [rq](http://python-rq.org/).

É bem simples de usar e tem até um [app](https://github.com/ui/django-rq) para Django que facilita a implementação.

Abraço!

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber pq alguém negativou essa resposta...